# Mysql JSON_ARRAY limiting size over network call

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js

I have connect MYSQL with node.js code to execute a query that returns a json array. The query when executed on SqlYog returns the complete array but when executed via node.js the array size is limited to 1024 characters.

I have already set `SET @@GLOBAL.group_concat_max_len = 10000000000;` but still the array is stripped off. Though JSON_OBJECT wrapping JSON_Array is not stripped.

Query I used:

```
Select JSON_OBJECT(id, JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{name:', name, ', status:', currentstatus, ', time:', updatetime,'}')))) from xyz
GROUP BY id, projectid;
```

Node.js code:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var mysql = require('mysql');
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
     host: 'localhost',
     user: 'root',
     password: 'root',
     database: 'db'
});

connection.connect();
app.post('/getStatus', function(req, res, next){
var queryStr = "Select JSON_OBJECT(id, JSON_ARRAY(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('{name:', name, ', status:', currentstatus, ', time:', updatetime,'}')))) from xyz
    GROUP BY id, projectid";
      console.log(queryStr);
   var query = connection.query(queryStr, function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return res.send(err);
     } else {
       return res.send(result);
     }
  });
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Comment: _"but when executed via node.js the array size is limited to 1024 characters."_ So why haven't you added any of the node.js code to the question?

Comment: @Cerbrus : edited the question

Comment: Can you check the value for the `max_allowed_packet`? E.g. - `SELECT @@SESSION.max_allowed_packet;`